# PagerTabStrip missing tab navigation panel

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, pagertabstrip

I am now learning to create tabbed activities and I've choosen `PagerTabStrip` to work with. But now when I'm created fragments, assigned them po Adapter, and assigned adapter to ViewPager, Tab navigation panel of `PagerTabStrip` is missing

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.player.pagertabstrip.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager">
        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top" />
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

> PageFragment.java

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class PageFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_PAGE_NUMBER = "page_number";

    public PageFragment() {
    }

    public static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
        PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE_NUMBER, page);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page_layout, container, false);

        TextView txt = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.page_number_label);
        int page = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE_NUMBER, -1);
        txt.setText(String.format("Page %d", page));

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

> fragment_page_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.player.pagertabstrip.PageFragment">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/page_number_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TabsPagerAdapter tabsPagerAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(tabsPagerAdapter);
    }
}
```

and screenshot of No tab navigation:-

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it seems to be bug in `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0` library.
I found 2 ways to solve this problem.

> First:

You must downgrade your library which used in your project. In your gradle file replace compile `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'` to compile `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'`

> Second:

You can change property of child `PagerTabStrip` by accessing via it's parent's LayoutParams

```
((ViewPager.LayoutParams) pagerTabStrip.getLayoutParams()).isDecor = true;
```